# Calculating FLOPS for Keras Models (TF 2.x)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow2.x, flops

I found two solutions to calculate FLOPS of Keras models (TF 2.x):

[1] https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32809#issuecomment-849439287

[2] https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32809#issuecomment-841975359

At first glance, both seem to work perfectly when testing with `tf.keras.applications.ResNet50()`. The resulting FLOPS are identical and correspond to the FLOPS of the ResNet paper.

But then I built a small GRU model and found different FLOPS for the two methods:

```
model = Sequential(name=self._modelName)
model.add(GRU(recurrentCells, input_shape=(10, 8), recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
model.add(GRU(recurrentCells, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(outputDimension, activation='tanh'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError(), MeanAbsoluteError()])
```

This results in the following numbers:
`13206` for method [1] and `18306` for method [2].
That is really confusing...

Does anyone know how to correctly calculate FLOPS of recurrent Keras models in TF 2.x?

**EDIT**

I found another information:

[3] https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36391#issuecomment-596055100

> It seems like when our model have the LSTM or GRU's layers, what we
> need to do is by pass one more argument lower_control_flow=False in
> order to make the convert_variables_to_constants_v2 work.

When adding this argument to `convert_variables_to_constants_v2`, the outputs of [1] and [2] are the same when using my GRU example.

The tensorflow documentation explains this argument as follows (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py):

> lower_control_flow: Boolean indicating whether or not to lower control
> flow ops such as If and While. (default True)

Can someone try to explain this?